# Can't include my own static library headers in external project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, premake

Im creating a really simple graphics framework as a learning project and thought I would try to better organize it and make it reusable, a separate project I could just include in any future project I might start. Im building it as a static library using premake for build configuration and it builds just fine. However, when I try to include any header file from my own library in an external project the compiler throws an error saying the include file couldn't be located (for example, if I try to include my "Window.hpp" in a external "Game" project, it throws "Cannot open include file: 'GLFW/glfw3.h').

**Should I add an include for this libraries in all projects that might use my own library?**

I thought it wouldn't be the case as in other graphics libraries it doesn't seem to be a thing, like in SFML or in the Hazel game engine made by youtuber TheCherno (pointed him out as Im building my projects based on the same design he was using in the beginning of the development of Hazel).

The solution directories are laid out as follows:

```
GraphicsLibrary
- Bin // For binaries
- Bin-int // For intermediates
- Cryon // Actual library
  - Dependencies // Stores all libraries used by Cryon, like GLFW and Glad. The binaries are 
                 // built in the solution "Bin" folder
  - Include
  - Source
  - premake5.lua
- Game // The project I use to test the functionality of my library
  - Source
    - Main.cpp // File where Im including Cryon's headers for testing
  - premake5.lua
- Dependencies.lua // Just to store the dependencies in arrays for easier access for the
                   // underlying projects
- premake5.lua // Actual premake file for the solution that includes the other projects
```

Here are the premake5.lua files I use to build the projects

Solution:

```
include "Dependencies.lua"

workspace "GraphicsLibrary"
    architecture "x86_64"
    startproject "Game"
    
    configurations
    {
        "Debug",
        "Release"
    }

    flags
    {
        "MultiProcessorCompile"
    }

    outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}"
    
    group "Dependencies"
        include "Cryon/Dependencies/GLFW"
        include "Cryon/Dependencies/GLAD"
    
    group ""
    include "Cryon"
    include "Game"
```

Library:

```
project "Cryon"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "c++"
    cppdialect "c++17"
    staticruntime "on"
    
    targetdir ("%{wks.location}/Bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("%{wks.location}/Bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    
    pchheader "CryonPCH.hpp"
    pchsource "Source/CryonPCH.cpp"
    
    files 
    {
        "Include/**.hpp",
        "Source/**.cpp"
    }
    
    defines
    {
        "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS",
        "GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE"
    }
    
    includedirs
    {
        "Include",
        "%{IncludeDirs.GLFW}", -- This get evaluated to "%{wks.location}/Cryon/Dependencies/GLFW"
        "%{IncludeDirs.GLAD}", -- All the others are similar
        "%{IncludeDirs.glm}",
        "%{IncludeDirs.spdlog}",
    }
    
    links
    {
        "GLFW",
        "Glad",
        "opengl32.lib"
    }
    
    filter "system:windows"
        systemversion "latest"
        defines {"CRYON_SYSTEM_WINDOWS"}

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "CRYON_DEBUG"
        runtime "Debug"
        symbols "on"
    
    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "CRYON_RELEASE"
        runtime "Release"
        optimize "on"
```

External game project:

```
project "Game"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "c++"
    cppdialect "c++17"
    staticruntime "off"
    
    targetdir ("%{wks.location}/Bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("%{wks.location}/Bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    
    files 
    {
        "Source/**.hpp",
        "Source/**.cpp"
    }
    
    includedirs
    {
        "%{wks.location}/Cryon/Include",
        "%{IncludeDirs.spdlog}"
    }
    
    links
    {
        "Cryon"
    }
    
    filter "system:windows"
        systemversion "latest"

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        runtime "Debug"
        symbols "on"
    
    filter "configurations:Release"
        runtime "Release"
        optimize "on"
        
    postbuildcommands
    {
        ("{COPYDIR} Assets %{cfg.targetdir}/Assets")
    }
```

Comment: Your header includes GLFW/glfw3.h. The compiler needs to find it somewhere every time your header is included anywhere. If you don't want this, perhaps you should redesign your library such that your headers do not include any headers from third-party libraries.

Comment: It's probably the approach I'll have to use, but thought I might have missed something or there was another way around it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There are many ways. If you ship your library with dependencies like GLFW, you should also ship it with build flags that say where to find said dependencies. Tools like pkg-config or autotools or cmake provide ways to do it transparently for the user. If you want your users to configure manually, then yes, the choice is limited.

Comment: Got it. Was checking SFMLs github page again and saw that the actual header files available to the users neve include third-party libraries, something I didn't noticed before. I'll probably redesign my own library to use a similar approach or actually make it so the user needs to give a window handle to the library (like a GLFWwindow*, SDL_Window* and so on) so it works with multiple windowing libraries (I'll probably need to use some build macros for this, I think). It's probably a little overkill for what I plan to do with it, but always seemed like something cool to do. Appreciate the help.